# Filtering a R DataFrame with repeated values in columns

Tags: r

I have a R DataFrame and I want to make another DF from this one, but only with the values which appears more than X times in a determinate column.

```
    >DataFrame
     Value Column
     1     a
     4     a
     2     b
     6     c
     3     c
     4     c
     9     a
     1     d
```

For example a want a new DataFrame only with the values in Column which appears more than 2 times, to get something like this:

```
    >NewDataFrame
     Value Column
     1     a
     4     a
     6     c
     3     c
     4     c
     9     a
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `table` to get the count of values in 'Column' and `subset` the dataset ('df1') based on the names in 'tbl' that have a count greater than 'n'

```
n <- 2
tbl <- table(DataFrame$Column) > n
NewDataFrame <- subset(DataFrame, Column %in% names(tbl)[tbl])
#    Value Column
#1     1      a
#2     4      a
#4     6      c
#5     3      c
#6     4      c
#7     9      a
```

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
NewDataFrame <- DataFrame[with(DataFrame, ave(Column, Column, FUN=length)>n),]
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
NewDataFrame <- setDT(DataFrame)[, .SD[.N>n] , by = Column]
```

Or

```
NewDataFrame <- setDT(DataFrame)[, if(.N > n) .SD, by = Column]
```

Or `dplyr`

```
NewDataFrame <- DataFrame %>%
                      group_by(Column) %>%
                      filter(n()>2)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not providing me a new dataframe only with the rows I need, but thank you really much

Comment: @CaptainNemo I am getting the desired output as you showed.  If this is not the desired output, you may have to show a different example that fails this code.

Comment: Or `setDT(df)[, if(.N > n) .SD, by = Column]` for efficiency

Comment: but @akrun I don't get a new DF which I can use

Comment: @CaptainNemo yes you are.

Comment: Ok... Where is it? @DavidArenburg

Comment: @CaptainNemo I think you want to assign it to a new object. i.e. `newDF <- subset(....`

Comment: Ok, I made all the edits I could think of. Can't get any clearer